# Sockets don't appear to be closing when using Node.js http.get

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

OS X 10.8.3

Node 0.10.0

I'm using the 'http' module to make requests of the Facebook graph API.

Here are the options that I pass to 'http.get':

```
var options = {host: 'graph.facebook.com',
               port: 80,
               path: '/' + fb_id + '/picture'};  //fb_id is a Facebook user identifier
```

My code looks like this:

```
http.get(options,
  function(res) {
    ...some stuff...
    DONE(RESULT);  //DONE is a callback function
  }).on('error', function(e) {
       ...some error handling...
});
```

What I observe is that I can only do as many requests as the value of http.globalAgent.maxSockets. Once I reach that many requests, the next call to http.get never (apparently) connects. I've verified that I'm not getting errors on the requests.

It's as though the sockets are not being closed after the response comes in.

Is there something I need to do as part of the response handler to ensure that the socket is closed?

Are these sockets not closing because of the default keepalive behavior?

How should I proceed to debug this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `agent: false` in the options. Default behaviour is indeed to keep connections open for HTTP keep-alive:

```
var options = {host: 'graph.facebook.com',
               port: 80,
               path: '/' + fb_id + '/picture',
               agent: false};
```

Comment: I saw this in the documentation but found it confusing:

"If no pending HTTP requests are waiting on a socket to become free the socket is closed. This means that node's pool has the benefit of keep-alive when under load but still does not require developers to manually close the HTTP clients using keep-alive."

I don't understand why the pooled, already open connections aren't used for the subsequent requests. I will try agent: false, and expect good things from it.

Comment: I think the `http` module doesn't queue any requests for which a socket isn't available in the pool. If `maxSockets` is reached and all those requests are still pending, any subsequent requests can't get a free socket from the pool and will just get dropped.

Comment: I realized that my application architecture was contributing to my problem since I was re-require-ing the 'http' module before each request, meaning that each http reference was standalone.

I attempted to change this so that the http module reference was shared across 'get' invocations, but I see the same behavior (first globalAgent.maxSockets requests are fine, the rest hang for want of a socket).

This begs the question - How would one take advantage of this default keepalive behavior?

Comment: Robert, your comment makes sense but I know that these responses are coming in successfully, and I would assume that means that the associated request is not still pending. 

I take the whole "keepalive" default behavior to mean "the http module will allow multiple get requests on the same socket without closing/re-opening it". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you are sure they are sent in turn, and not while other requests to the same host are still pending (since we're talking async, that might be difficult but it comes down to how you implement your workflow), I don't know why you're still hitting the `maxSockets` limit (unless it's set unreasonably low).

Comment: Just encountered the same problem and indeed agent:false "solves" it but I'm nervous about this solution because I feel like maybe under enough pressure (i.e. with enough simultaneous requests being made) something deeper beneath the hood would break. @robertklep, can you point me to a resource that explains how Node acquires sockets? I'm trying to understand who the ultimate socket keeper is. If I have 10 Node  Express instances running on the same OS (on 10 different ports), do they share a pool from the OS? Or are they all 100% independent?

Comment: @GeniaS. Node _processes_ are independent, there is no shared socket pool between them or anything. As of Node 0.12, `maxSockets` is set to `Infinity`, so apparently the previous (pre-0.12) limit (of 5, I believe) was deemed to be too restrictive. At some point, with thousands of concurrent connections to a remote HTTP server, you _will_ run into issues, but limiting the # of concurrent requests can better be done explicitly, in code, instead of through some hardcoded default.

Answer (score 2):

Node's http module states that agent defaults to global agent: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent, which means that keep-alive is shared regardless of the module that origins the request.

BTW, responding to Wes' comment of Apr9'13 at 20:47: it does not matter how many times you load a node module, it will be loaded only once and share by all the modules.

What you're experiencing is a pool exhaustion problem. The simplest way to avoid it is to use a new agent (http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) with your desired maxSockets. Remember that the agent you create can be shared between modules if you place it in an export of that module (modules in node are stateful!!!) .

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same behavior, except that my connections were finally reused after a timeout period. Check if the connections are reused after a certain period of time (couple of minutes), and also check if response headers contain 'Connection: keep-alive'.

If that's the case a possible solution would be to use the 'Connection: Close' header instead of keep-alive, that way pooled connections could be reused earlier as in the usual setup. I am not sure if this leads to any performance issues using the facebook endpoints.

```
var options = {host: 'graph.facebook.com',
               port: 80,
               path: '/' + fb_id + '/picture',
               headers: { 'Connection':'Close' }
};
```

For me using agent:false did not work because the vast number of requests I sent exhausted server resources.